# SQL compare row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2017

I'm looking for a stored procedure to compare row by row in a table. For example, I have a table

```
id | fruit  | farmer |     plant_time      |  status
-------------------------------------------------------
1  | banana | John   | 2021-02-02 18:00:01 |   true
2  | apple  | Steve  | 2021-02-02 18:00:30 |   true   <<<<
3  | apple  | Steve  | 2021-02-02 18:01:10 |   true   <<<<  flag to false
4  | orange | Steve  | 2021-02-02 18:01:50 |   true
```

I want to find out same fruit same farmer and the difference between plant_time not more than one minute and flag the status to false.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @GordonLinoff I can't find other tag, actually I'm using 2017 version

Comment: @RoyalCambodia . . . I found it for you.  I suspected as much and wonder why the 2008 tag is easier to find than more recent versions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff alright thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to find out same fruit same farmer and the difference between plant_time not more than one minute and flag the status to false.

In any supported version of SQL Server, you can use `lag()` or `lead()`.  As you have expressed the problem:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lead(planttime) over (partition by farmer order by planntime) < dateadd(minute, 1, planttime)
             then 'false' else 'true'
        end) as status
from t;
```

If you want to update the value, you can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             (case when lead(planttime) over (partition by farmer order by planntime) < dateadd(minute, 1, planttime)
                   then 'false' else 'true'
              end) as new_status
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set status = new_status
    where status is null or status <> new_status;
```

Note you *can* do this in SQL Server 2008 using `apply` or a correlated subquery.  However, I suspect you are not using unsupported commercial software.

Second, often it is the *first* in such a sequence that would be flagged rather than the last one.  In that case, you would use `lag()` instead of `lead()` (and adjust the time comparison).

Comment: Great answer, but I still need to add another field which is fruit, where is same as lead(fruit)

Comment: @RoyalCambodia . . . That is not the question you asked here.  You might be able to solve the problem by adding `fruit` to the `partition by`.  If it is not that simple you should ask a new question and be explicit about your question.